# "Base SDK Missing", how do i set the minimum required OS to ex 4.0 in sdk 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdk, radix

What I want to do is to set the minimum required OS to 4.0 instead of 4.2<...
Is there anyway to set the base sdk to 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the “iOS Deployment Target” value in build settings to control the minimum required OS.